# Count the number of times word appears in a single column

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm attempting to count the number of times apples and oranges appear in my fruit column.
The table looks like this:

```
Fruit
-------
Apples
Apples Oranges
Apples Oranges
Apples
Oranges
```

Expected output:

```
Apples 4 
Oranges 3
```

My code thus far. I'm not sure how to do it when both appear and how to add them to the totals. I'm sure there is an easier way that this.

```
SELECT 
     COUNT (CASE WHEN Fruit LIKE '%Apples%' THEN '1' END) AS Apples
     COUNT (CASE WHEN Fruit LIKE '%Oranges%' THEN '1' END) AS Oranges
FROM Fruits
```

Cheers

Comment: Your method is fine.

Comment: Its not correct, my output is 4 Apples, 1 Orange.

Comment: . . Your code works fine:  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=54d9b5c1d34b63d140a94d7d77738e69.

Comment: you code works without issues. 4 apples and 3 oranges

Comment: Ah yes you're all right!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If those fruits are single-worded and separated by a space, then such a *generic* approach might be interesting for you.

Lines #1 - 8 represent sample data; you already have that so you don't type it. Code you might need starts at line #10.

```
SQL> with fruit (fruit) as
  2  -- sample data; you have that in a table
  3    (select 'Apples'         from dual union all
  4     select 'Apples Oranges' from dual union all
  5     select 'Apples Oranges' from dual union all
  6     select 'Apples Lemon'   from dual union all
  7     select 'Oranges Plums'  from dual
  8    ),
  9  -- split fruits to rows
 10  temp as
 11    (select regexp_substr(fruit, '[^ ]+', 1, column_value) fruit
 12     from fruit cross join
 13       table(cast(multiset(select level from dual
 14                           connect by level <= regexp_count(fruit, ' ') + 1
 15                          ) as sys.odcinumberlist))
 16    )
 17  select fruit, count(*)
 18  from temp
 19  group by fruit
 20  order by fruit;

FRUIT                                                      COUNT(*)
-------------------------------------------------------- ----------
Apples                                                            4
Lemon                                                             1
Oranges                                                           3
Plums                                                             1

SQL>
```

Answer (score 1):

Either with sum or count, it works

Connected to:
Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production

```
SQL> with t as
(
select 'Apples'            as fruits from dual union all
select 'Apples Oranges'    as fruits from dual union all
select 'Apples Oranges'    as fruits from dual union all
select 'Apples'            as fruits from dual union all
select 'Oranges'           as fruits  6   from dual
) select
     SUM (CASE WHEN fruits LIKE '%Apples%' THEN '1' END) AS Apples ,
     SUM (CASE WHEN fruits LIKE '%Oranges%' THEN '1' END) AS Oranges
FROM t 
  ;

 APPLES    ORANGES
---------- ----------
         4          3

SQL> with t as
    (
 select 'Apples'            as fruits from dual union all
select 'Apples Oranges'    as fruits from dual union all
 select 'Apples Oranges'    as fruits from dual union all
select 'Apples'            as fruits from dual union all
select 'Oranges'           as fruits from dual
) select
     COUNT (CASE WHEN fruits LIKE '%Apples%' THEN '1' END) AS Apples ,
     COUNT (CASE WHEN fruits LIKE '%Oranges%' THEN '1' END) AS Oranges
FROM t   ;

    APPLES    ORANGES
---------- ----------
         4          3

SQL>
```

Comment: There seem to be a lot of stray numbers in your code, e.g. `2    3    4    5  select 'Apples Oranges'`. Is that intended?

Comment: @WilliamRobertson , that is normal when you are printing lines in sqlplus by copy paste from an editor.

Comment: So your code is normally full of random numbers and you leave them there?

Comment: No, it's not normal. I'm not sure how you are using SQL*Plus for this to happen. It means nobody can copy and paste your code without manually removing a bunch of random numbers.

Comment: What I meant by "normal" is that when you copy the content from an editor (like Notepad ++) into SQL*Plus the number are pasted, although they are not interpreted by the CLI. Surely, it is an inconvenient when you try to copy & paste the code from here to any other place, so I removed them, but come on, this is not a big deal. They are not a bunch or "random numbers" as you said, they are the lines. If you try to copy the code from @Littelfoot, you can see the line numbers as well, and I did not see you trying to tell him the same as you are trying to tell me.

Comment: It’s always better if people can copy & paste the code directly without having to edit it. You don’t see stray line numbers in Java and HTML answers. At least with Littlefoot’s code most editors can delete a vertical block with a single alt-mouse-drag, and the code still lines up so you can read it without random sections being a mile to the right.